Is the atomic sentence “There is something” the starting point for all possible human inquiry about anything at all?
I have been developing a sort of foundational basis for not merely philosophy, but all forms of human inquiry. To me it seems obvious that the proposition There is something must be true because of the principal of non-contradiction: “There is nothing” is contradictory because that proposition itself is at least one thing.
What I am more concerned with is this: When any human being starts an inquiry into anything, is it universally true that they all accept this proposition as the necessary starting point for any inquiry, or otherwise assume it subconsciously, or is there any philosopher, system of thought or inquiry which believes that this statement is either false which would mean that they would have to agree that “There is nothing” or which believes that it is true but not a necessary proposition to accept to engage in inquiry about anything, or otherwise believe that is nonsensical? I have been thinking about this for a couple months and I am almost certain that all must accept this as THE FIRST PROPOSITION for any inquiry about anything at all.
Perhaps I am missing something or I am completely abusing or trivializing language. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Interestingly, “there is something” isn’t a first order logical form sentence by itself, so there is an argument that it’s not a proposition. However, the existential idiom is key to first order logic, so I guess my question is how important the “atomic sentence” part of your question is, or whether discussion about existing things is where you want an answer to go!

@andrós, I do think Christianity poisons the waters of a lot of these discussions.  The idea that “something exists” needs to be true in order to ground a metaphysics strikes me as very muddled thinking. But there is some interesting discussion to be had around existence as a philosophical concept - the question is, is this what OP is looking for?

@PaulRoss Why would you say that it is muddled thinking?

@MattHarper, I’ll start with this: what is “something”? “Things” are the stuff of metaphysics - we aren’t sure what, or even if, any given “things” exist. The reason “something exists” seems to be metaphysically important is its conclusions, but there is a lot of metaphysics smuggled in to “something” already. Do we need to subscribe to a prior view of the logical structure of reality to accept this premise, and if so, what is that view, and do we all agree on it?

I would treat the OP's attempt as a variant of Descartes' cogit ergo sum

I think There is something is just another way of saying [at least] something exists. I don't see how that's any more "fundamental" than Descartes'  “I think therefore I am. It's a potentially unwarranted assumption that anything else apart from "I, the thinker" exists.

Yes. “There is something “ is a fundamental starting point of all inquiry. It is a more fundamental assertion than “ I think therefore I am” .
